# How to Single Image Predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I have a code that using random images to predict.
The [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlUSH.png) is on comment section

**

That was an random image predict, how to predict an single image? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's ok to place your code directly into your question

Comment: @axtck it is not "ok", it is how it must be done

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the image to either TF Dataset or Numpy and you can just feed to model.predict as given below.

```
im = Image.open(data_path)
im = im.resize((128,128))
im_array = np.array(im)
im_array = np.expand_dims(im_array, axis = 0)
pred = model.predict(im_array)
print("the probable class according to the model is {} with confidence :.2f}".format(class_names[np.argmax(pred)], np.max(pred)*100))
```

Comment: the full code is here, can you help me with single image pred code ?https://stackoverflow.com/a/67479946/15888989